# Select full row when clicking on rowheader in a Datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have set my selection mode on my datagridview to be cell select only. But I need to select full row when i click on the rowheader. How would i achieve that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
```

This will allow you to select full row as well as indivdual cells.

Comment: thanks. didnt now it was that simple.. i will accept ur answer in 3 mins :)

Answer (score 1):

you can also set it in datagridview's properties - SelectionMode set to FullRowMode